# Mul column of two Data frames with reference column. Python

Tags: python, pandas

Mul columns of two Data frames with reference column.

Getting error: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

```
#DF1:
  Country   Score
-----------------
1  Ireland    0.5
2  Spain      0.25 
3  USA        0.75
4  Canada     0.5
5  India      0.75
.
.
.

Df2:
---
   Sup  By_Id   Country   unique_orders
------------------------------------
1   1     1      India      210
2   2     4      CZ          20
3   3     2      Canada     321
4   1     6      Spain       30
5   2     7      India      213
.
.
```

Want to multiply score of DF1 with unique_orders with reference to Country

For that

```
DF2['Weighted_Score'] = DF2.unique_orders.mul(DF2.Country.map(B_Score.set_index('Country').Score))
```

But now getting error: **Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects**

Comment: Does your df1 `Country` column have duplicate items?

Comment: Yes, I got this in DB same DF store multiple times.

Comment: If df1 `Country` column has duplicate items, it means each Country can have multiple score. which score do you want to use to `df2`?